# Change paragraph text and highlight on menu item click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display custom text based on the menu option on-click (javascript). The menu item selected is intended to be highlighted with a provided color too (css).

The text appears on click but just disappears in a fraction and the menu item is not getting the highlighted color too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
  .selectedNav{
    background-color: #38C1D2;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <aside>
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <div style="float:left;width:100px;">
        <nav id="main-nav">
          <a href="" class=selectedNav onclick="setSelectedTab('home')"><i class="material-icons md-36">home</i><p>Home</p></a>
          <a href="" onclick="setSelectedTab('projects')"><i class="material-icons md-36">image</i><p>Projects</p></a>
          <a href="" onclick="setSelectedTab('about')"><i class="material-icons md-36">person</i><p>About</p></a>
          <a href="" onclick="setSelectedTab('contact')"><i class="material-icons md-36">mail</i><p>Contact</p></a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:101px;border-radius:5px;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:150px;height:100%;">
        <p id="navDescription" style="padding:10px;"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function setSelectedTab(selected){
    if(selected === 'home')
    {
      document.getElementById('main-nav').querySelectorAll("a")[0].className = "selectedNav";
      texttoshow = "<u>WELCOME</u><br><br>Thanks for visiting my site...<br>Scroll down to learn more about me... ";
    }
    else if(selected === 'projects')
    {
      document.getElementById('main-nav').querySelectorAll("a")[1].className = "selectedNav";
      texttoshow = "Check on my projects here..";
    }
    else if(selected === 'about')
    {
      document.getElementById('main-nav').querySelectorAll("a")[2].className = "selectedNav";
      texttoshow = "Learn more about me here.. ";
    }
    else if(selected == 'contact')
    {
      document.getElementById('main-nav').querySelectorAll("a")[3].className = "selectedNav";
      texttoshow = "Reach me by sending a message";
    }
    document.getElementById("navDescription").innerHTML = texttoshow;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the home text to be displayed as the default until other menu options are clicked.

Comment: You haven't written any code to change the color/CSS class of the selected item. Where did you expect that to happen?

Comment: Sorry i missed the code. I have updated it the way i tried. But that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code on a browser and look closely at the reload button, you will notice that it blinks when you click on a link. that means that the page is reloading every time you click on a link, and that's why the text appears than disappears fast, because the page reloads into to its original state. To fix that problem you set the **href** attribute of the **a** tag to **"#"**

```
      <a href="#" class=selectedNav onclick="setSelectedTab('home')"><i class="material-icons md-36">home</i><p>Home</p></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="setSelectedTab('projects')"><i class="material-icons md-36">image</i><p>Projects</p></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="setSelectedTab('about')"><i class="material-icons md-36">person</i><p>About</p></a>
      <a href="#" onclick="setSelectedTab('contact')"><i class="material-icons md-36">mail</i><p>Contact</p></a>
```

You can also set the default *#navDescription* text to the "Home page" text in the html

```
<p id="navDescription" style="padding:10px;">
 <u>WELCOME</u><br><br>Thanks for visiting my site...<br>Scroll down or use the navigation to check on my projects and learn more about me... 
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was stuck with this for the past couple days n now its fixed.